# unicorn failing to start on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, ubuntu-15.04

I'm following an installation tutorial for unicorn and nginx using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) on ubuntu 15.04. Everything works until the section "Create Unicorn Init Script" where I create the init script, change the required variables, change the permissions and then run

```
sudo service unicorn_my_app start
```

Where I get an error that reads

```
Job for unicorn_my_app.service failed. See "systemctl status unicorn_my_app.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

When I run

```
systemctl status unicorn_my_app.service
```

The output is:

```
● unicorn_my_app.service - LSB: starts the unicorn app server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/unicorn_my_app)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-09-27 23:22:49 PDT; 1min 19s ago
  Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 26576 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/unicorn_my_app start (code=exited, status=127)
```

What is happening? why won't unicorn start?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find out why Unicorn didn't start?

Comment: Hi, also having the same issue? did you manage to resolve it?